# How to access input elements through the angularjs forms collection that are encapsulated in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to access input elements of a forms collection to do some custom validation. This worked just fine like this:
 `scope.myForm.value3.$setValidity('complex', valid);` 
until I converted value3 into a directive which in turn contains the input element named value3. Now I have no access to the underlying input element of the directive any more.

The important code goes as follows ([working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgnTqVMxcom9PpLe4Z1S?p=preview)):

```
<form name="myForm" two-values>
      <input id="value1" name="value1" ng-model="f.v1"/>
      <input id="value2" name="value2" ng-model="f.v2"/>
      <szp-input id="value3" value="f.v3"></szp-input>
</form>

app.directive('twoValues', function ($parse) {
    function isValid(scope, value1, value2) {
        var valid = true;
        if (value1 == 0 && value2 == 0) {
            valid = false;
        } else if (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0) {
            valid = false;
        }
        console.log(scope.myForm);
        // note that I can access value1 and value2, but not value3
        // which is encapsulated in a directive
        scope.myForm.value1.$setValidity('complex', valid);
        scope.myForm.value2.$setValidity('complex', valid);
        // this throws and error saying that value3 is undefined 
        scope.myForm.value3.$setValidity('complex', false);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('f.v1', function () {
                isValid(scope, scope.f.v1, scope.f.v2);
            });
            scope.$watch('f.v2', function () {
                isValid(scope, scope.f.v1, scope.f.v2);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with how your `szpInput` directive is getting completely compiled/linked after the `form` directive has done it's work.  What I noticed in your version of the code was that the form did have your custom value but it stored it as `myForm.{{id}}` which tells us that the `form` picked it up before AngularJs was able to transclude the value for `{{id}}` in the name attribute.

How I got it to work was by passing a function to the `template` attribute in the directive, instead of using `templateUrl`.  In the template function I am building your template and setting the actual value for the `name` and `id` attributes.

```
app.directive('szpInput', function ($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            id: "@id",
            value: "=value"
        },
        template: function(elem,attrs) {
          var elemTpl = '<input type="text"'
            + ' ng-model="value"' 
            + ' id="' + attrs.id + '"'
            + ' name="' + attrs.id + '"'
            + ' class="form-control input-sm"/>';
          return elemTpl;
        }
    };
});
```

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUnsErIuH7APqC8Jlw6H?p=preview)

I have a feeling that something similar can be accomplished by using `complile` and/or the `$complile` service but I'm not too familiar with how to best use them.

Comment: So, you basically say I should dump templateUrl and use template instead. It does seem to work, but man, it is ugly. Hate to use html code as a string. I would really like to have the html in a separate file.